# Calculate middle between two vectors with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

I need to calculate the coordinates of the middle between two vectors and I'm sure it's very easy to do, but I don't see how.

[image]

I draw a line between two objects but I couldn't find the middle.

Any idea ? :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the two vectors, then use another Vector Math node and divide the sum of the two vectors by 2.

Comment: Instead of adding i was substracting :(
Thank you !